# How to get the values of a group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, series

I have a `pandas` `series` that is the return value of a `groupby` operation. The data looks like this:

```
year  month
2010  8       -0.062911
      9        0.057910
      10       0.033854
      11      -0.000337
      12       0.044635
2011  1        0.012829
      2        0.018433
...
```

How do I get the third column (the values, NOT the year/month) of this `series`?

Comment: just get the values using numpy : `finalseries.to_numpy()` ? or `finalseries.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the values of the series you can type:

```
my_series.values
```

This will return a list of all values.

Answer (score 0):

#### Depending on what's the intended usage and how real the *values* you want to get:

Although [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) is commonly seen, it may have had been converted from the actual data into a different form.

From the [official document of `.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html), you can see that there is a warning regarding the usage of `.values`:

> **Warning**
>
> We recommend using ***Series.array*** or ***Series.to_numpy()***, depending on
> whether you need a reference to the underlying data or a NumPy array.

**1) If you need a refernce to the underlying Series data (the actual data)**, you should use:

[`Series.array`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html)   *(Zero-copy view to the array backing the Series)*

The official doc mentions that:

> [Series.array] returns ExtensionArray An ExtensionArray of the values stored within.
> For [Pandas] extension types, **this is the actual array**. For NumPy native types,
> this is a thin (no copy) wrapper around numpy.ndarray.
>
> **.array differs .values which may require converting the data to a
> different form.**

Note the highlighted text which reveals that `.array` presents a more *original / real / actual* data than `.values`.

Thus, if you want to get the *original / real* data values of the Series, [`Series.array`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html) is the choice.

From your sample data, calling [`Series.array`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html) gives:

```
<PandasArray>
[-0.062911, 0.05791, 0.033854, -0.000337, 0.044635, 0.012829, 0.018433]
Length: 7, dtype: float64
```

**2) If you need to get a numpy array,** as seen from the warning of the [official document of `.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) shown above, [`Series.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) is the official recommended choice.

From your sample data, calling [`Series.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) gives:

```
array([-0.062911,  0.05791 ,  0.033854, -0.000337,  0.044635,  0.012829,
        0.018433])
```

The `array([...])` notation indicates that it is a **numpy** array.

**3) If you need to get a Python list** (e.g. for compatibility purpose with other Python entities), you can use [`Series.to_list()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html)

From your sample data, calling [`Series.to_list()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) gives:

```
[-0.062911, 0.05791, 0.033854, -0.000337, 0.044635, 0.012829, 0.018433]
```